# android - BufferOverflowException when trying to unzip obb file

Tags: android

when I try to unzip a encrypted obb file using the jobb tool jumps me the following error:

```
jobb -dump /temp/obb-output/ -o my-app-assets.obb -k secret-key

Package Name: com.example.sample
Package Version: 1
SALT: -63dddd10f3a63bb

29eb26a5c9227f6efeab677fc53a7348
[LFN = video.avi / SFN = ShortName [/> ifl -- 5 2f 1d 10 3 3e c 1d 69 66 6c ]]

Alignment off reading from sector: 2433
Partial read from sector: 2433
Exception in thread "main" java.nio.BufferOverflowException
    at java.nio.HeapByteBuffer.put(HeapByteBuffer.java:183)
    at java.nio.ByteBuffer.put(ByteBuffer.java:832)
    at com.android.jobb.EncryptedBlockFile$EncryptedBlockFileChannel.readDecryptedSector(EncryptedBlockFile.java:292)
    at com.android.jobb.EncryptedBlockFile$EncryptedBlockFileChannel.read(EncryptedBlockFile.java:142)
    at de.waldheinz.fs.util.FileDisk.read(FileDisk.java:118)
    at de.waldheinz.fs.fat.ClusterChain.readData(ClusterChain.java:214)
    at de.waldheinz.fs.fat.FatFile.read(FatFile.java:126)
    at com.android.jobb.Main.dumpDirectory(Main.java:137)
    at com.android.jobb.Main.dumpDirectory(Main.java:112)
    at com.android.jobb.Main.main(Main.java:315)
```

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0):

It is to do with expansion file version numbers. I just needed to increment versionCode in my manifest and in the obb file. Android doesn't seem to like you updating with a new obb file with the same version number, Hope it helps.